# How to configure a conky file?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, conky

How can I change the conky theme? I have the text(code) for conky vision but I have no idea what to do with it, or where to put it? I'm running Linux Mint btw

Comment: Is my answer clear enough for you to solve this issue?

Comment: unfortunately I haven't had the chance to try it yet. very buisy atm. will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Yeah. No problem. Take your time.

Answer (score 0):

In Conky Vision GitHub page there are installing instructions:

> Installation
>
> You can run the install script, or you can do it manually:
>
> Install conky, curl and jq.
>
> Install the Poiret One font.
>
> Move the .conky-vision folder & .conkyrc file into your ~ dir.
>
> NOTE some files/folders are hidden; unhide them.

From:
https://github.com/zagortenay333/conky-Vision/blob/master/README.md